# Spring Transaction in JSF

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2, spring-transactions

Using Spring 3.1,Mojarra ,Hibernate

applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    ... 
    </bean>     

    <tx:annotation-driven  />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage"/>
```

TestBean.java

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class TestBean {

@Autowired private @Getter @Setter HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate=null;

public String submit(){
    try{
        this.test();
    }catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addWarn("Error");
    }

    return null;
}

@Transactional
public String test() {

    Device d1=new Device();
    hibernateTemplate.persist(d1);

    if(1==1)
        throw new RuntimeException("Testing");

    Device d2=new Device();
    hibernateTemplate.persist(d2);
    return null;
}

}
```

This works(rolled back) ,but shows exception in browser

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{testBean.test}"/>
```

Tried to show faces message ,but this commits d1

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{testBean.submit}"/>
```

Calling some other bean's(DAO) transactional method too works,but I would like to have the code in managed bean itself.How should I handle transaction in JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move transactional methods to yet another layer or use `TransactionTemplate` if you wish to avoid it for some reason:

```
  public String test() {
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

    try {
      txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
          // your transactional code here;
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle exception here
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better go for layered architecture Service and DAO layer, directly handling transactions in managed bean defeats the purpose of Single Responsibility Principle of a class.

Managed Bean soul purpose should be for navigation handling and gateway for data from view layer to service layer where you can perform main business logic or use case and delegate data persistence to DAO layer.

As far as messages to UI are concerned you can catch exceptions from service layer and populate required message accordingly.

This way things are more manageable and maintainable and testable. Mock your service layer, test DAO for data persistence and Managed Bean for view layer.

Spring uses proxy/AOP for magical @Transactional to take place and its better you code to interface as it has its own issues if you dont code to interface i.e direct proxy to an interface or CGLIB subclass for injection. Look in docs for  tag for proxy setting for better understanding what I mean by code to interface.

Note: HibernateTemplate is considered an Anti Pattern and removed from Hibernate 4 support just a pointer so you can act accordingly if on Hibernate 3.

Hope this helps !!!!!